# How to print Using Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have developed a vb.net application. My application offers some reporting facilities like sales report etc...I have generated the report by using the dataset option i.e. setting the dataset to be the source for the crystal report. I just want my application to print the report when the user clicks the "generate report" button on the Windows Form...Can anyone help me on how can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

I use something along the lines off:

Imports in the class:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
```

And then:

```
Private sub print_report()
```

For parameters etc

```
    Dim pFields As New ParameterFields()
    Dim pField As New ParameterField()
    Dim disVal As New ParameterDiscreteValue()

    Try
        Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor

        Dim report_to_print As New report_name
```

add parameters (ignore if not neeeded)

```
       report_to_print.SetParameterValue("@parameter", parameter)
```

You also need a form that holds the crystal report viewer control (here frmReportViewer) and pass the report to it (code for this after)

```
       Dim frmReportViewer As New frmReportViewer(report_to_print)
```

pass parameters (if required)

```
       frmReportViewer.cryrepviewer.ParameterFieldInfo = pFields
```

show report

```
       frmReportViewer.ShowDialog()


 Catch ex As System.Exception

    'your own error handling code here

 Finally
        Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
 End Try
End Sub
```

frmReportViewer - this contains display, saving, printing controls :

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class frmReportViewer Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

   Dim mViewerRep As New ReportDocument

  Public Sub New(ByVal pViewerRep As ReportDocument)

    MyBase.New()

    'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    mViewerRep = pViewerRep

  End Sub

  Private Sub cryRepViewer_Load() Handles cryrepviewer.Load


      cryrepviewer.ReportSource = mViewerRep
      cryrepviewer.Refresh()
      Me.Text = ""

    End Sub
End Class
```